# Android sizes, real concern. What folder to use?

Tags: android, scale, resolution, pixel, android-screen-support

I've read a lot about scaling in Android and there are a lot of different opinions. But I feel this is really important to understand so maybe someone could explain.

For instance, I'm making a game using a lot of bitmaps of .png-pics, I'm putting everything in the res/drawable/mdpi-folder. I only plan to launch this game for phones, so no tablets.

I'm using a galaxy nexus which is hdpi, and everything looks fine on it. But will it look fine on phones with mdpi and xhdpi? I'm not using any density pixels, I tried using `canvas.setDensity(320)` but then I read somewhere that this should be avoided.

Does anyone have any experience with this? because I have none, and can't test on other phones because all my friends have iPhones.

I'm just worried my bitmaps might look giant or tiny on other phones that are not hdpi like mine, which will of course ruin the game.

Comment: why not test it in emulators?

Comment: never actually thought of that... But still, wanted to know more about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not provide hdpi resources your game will look crappy on hdpi devices. Here's why - your base density is mdpi. So your 400x400 dp image will be rendered as is on mdpi devices only. If you want the same size on ldpi, you have to scale your image by 0.75 (no big deal) but for hdpi your image needs to be 1.5 times bigger and for xhdpi devices, 2.0 times the size of your mdpi. So if there is no dedicated drawable, upscale would happen. And this rarely looks good (in most case you end up with blurry graphics). So I always put drawables in res/drawable-mdpi folder while developing. Once I got code ready for release I add hdpi resources to res/drawables-hdpi. I personally do not care ldpi devices as mostly no device I target is lower density than mdpi and if anyone will have such, then I am fine with android framework doing the downscale. But the upscaling is other story - you will always get bad results (blurry images) as you simply cannot technically make bigger bitmap from smaller without artifacts (no, CSI lies ;) - you simply got not enough data so you have to extrapolate. So it's better to provide proper drawables yourself or your end users would complain and your app may look not as nice as it could.

Comment: okey, so if my sprite is 50x50 for mdpi, I should just rescale it to 75x75 and put it in hdpi aswell? and it will look the same size-wise? no coding needed?

Comment: btw, I never write any code to convert image sizes to dp, I just add them in mdpi and start using them. Will this matter?

Comment: no, not rescale (at least no upscaling). If you got bitmap 50x50 then it does not matter if you rescale it up in Gimp/PS or framework would do that. The result will be blurry anyway. You should know the rules and **prepare** your assets right. It is always better to downscale if you work on bitmaps. So if you want to support `hdpi` and `mdpi` you should have your graphics made (best) for both resolutions, but it that is too expensive, make 75x75 (for `hdpi`) and create `mdpi` by downscaling.

Comment: ok I get what ur saying.. Ill have to downscale then. I just tried adding pic in `hdpi` with the same size that I have in `mdpi` and loaded on my phone, but no re-scaling happened. any reasons for this? is it because Im not converting to dps?

Comment: If you got `mdpi` resource (like drawable) and device is `hdpi` AND there's no hdpi versin of that drawablem then Android would "build" one on the fly scaling. But you provided drawable so it used it without any processing. And it looked wrong I guess (image was too small) because it was still 50x50 (as you said you copied it) but the density of `hdpi` is higher. To make it look the same size it had to be 75x75

Comment: yeah I finally got it. One last question. when making a UI for your game, HP-bars, steering etc. Do you convert pixels to dp for the best result or can you add something like this: `canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, view.getWidth() - bitmap.getWidth() - 20, 20, null);` this will add something in upper right corner, but will it look right on all devices aslong as I provide the right drawable for this bitmap?

Comment: btw, wouldnt it be best to make originals for xhdpi then downscaleing? instead of making them for hdpi

Comment: `dp` is measurement unit. If you use android framework to handle your UI then design all in `dp` and do not bother. If you draw all yourself on bitmaps, then you need to know what are your real pixels. I suggest you design all your app to use `dp` and then convert to "real" pixels getting scale factor like this: `float screenDensity = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;` and multiply your `dp` pixels by this density: `int realX = myDpX * screenDensity;`

Comment: As for `xhdpi` vs  `hdpi` resources question - yes - it would be better to make as hi-res as possible (or vector if you can have it that way) and then downscale (or render). Downscaling is always better than upscaling if you got no vector representation

Comment: in above example, what is `myDpX` and where did you get it from?

Comment: `myDpX` is your value. Say you want to put sprite on bitmap at postiopn X=50. You have to assume some units, to it is best to use `dp`. But your app can run on hdpi device and if you put at x=50 on the screen, you miss the right place. you need to do the math to find out real. phisical value of your 50 on that screen

Comment: aha, ok, so in that case it would be `int realX = 50 * screenDensity` . thank you for all your help, I have some re-positioning to do ^^

Comment: I will have to use this on alot of places. Couldnt I just write a method like: `public float getDens(int px){ screenDensity = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density; return px * screenDensity;}` or will this be slower then just calculating it before every position-change.

Comment: You can assume `getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density` is static per device (unless you are rooted and tweaked some portions of the platform) so reading it everytime is quite pointless. Just set variable to it once on app's startup or onCreate() or any place like that and use.

Comment: yeah that makes sence, thanks! gonna leave u alone now ^^ thanks for everything

Comment: ok one last thing, Lets say im testing my game on a device that is xhdpi (I am using nexus that is xhdpi, so xhdpi is my "baseline"), then if a pic is 960x640 (a background), that pic should be 960x640*0.75 for hdpi, and 960x640*0.5for mdpi? just want to be 100% before I start changing everything in my game

Comment: what device you mean by "nexus" exactly? As for formulas: if `hpdi = mdpi * 1,5` then `mdpi = hdpi/1.5`. Elementary math :)

Comment: galaxy nexus. But is that rly true? cus `480*1,5 = 720`(hdpi), `480*2=960`(xhdpi). but `960/1,5!=720`(xhdpi->hdpi) if I want do downscale xhdpi to hdpi, while `960*0,75=720`(xhdpi->hdpi).

Comment: I get it now, the `currentScreenSize/1,5 = downScaledSize` dosnt work when downscaling from xhpdi->hdpi. since `0,75` and `0,5`gives me the correct values, thats the way Im gonna go :) dont want my animator to do multiple versions (will take more time = more money) so I will be asking for xhdpi size so I can downscale.